# how can i check if 2 lists have the same cyclic order in python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def cyclic(lst1,lst2):
    a=lst1
    b=lst2
    if a == b:
        return True
    if a != b:
        return False
```

Hi, I'm writing a function in Python which checks if 2 lists (lst1,lst2) have the same cyclic order. [if yes-the function returns True, if not-it returnes False].
I've already managed to check weather the lists are identical or not.
but i need to check the the cyclic order. for example:[0,1,2,3]
and [3,0,1,2] should return True, while [0,1,2,3] and [3,1,0,2] should return false.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
def cyclic(l1, l2):
    if len(l1) != len(l2):
        return False
    if not l1:
        return True
    a = l1[0]
    for i, x in enumerate(l2):
        if a == x:
            if l1 == l2[i:] + l2[:i]:
                return True
    return False
```

Here we walk through the elements of `l2` looking for elements that match `l1[0]`.  When we find one, we rotate the list so that element is at the front, then compare the two lists.